# Importing function with an alias in Haskell

Tags: haskell, import

In Haskell, I write `import Fruit` or `import Fruit (apple)`  and can access `apple` or `Fruit.apple`.

In Python, I can write `from Fruit import apple` for `apple` or `import Fruit` for `Fruit.apple`.

I think can also write `import Fruit.apple as banana` in Python to reference the same function as `banana`.

How, in Haskell can I do this? `import Fruit as Vegetable` in either language can rename Fruit, but I want to rename apple.

Comment: For your information, I'm in particular at this moment trying to import Data.List.genericLength as length to get rid of Int without refactoring.

Comment: I wonder how easy or hard it would be to patch GHC to accept the following syntax: `import Fruit (apple as banana)`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is a nice property Python has because its "dictionaries all the way down," so to speak.
Haskell allows you to assign aliases to modules, but there is no way to alias functions
from the `import` statement (as far as I know). The best you would be able to do is

```
import qualified Fruit as F (apple)
banana = F.apple
```

You could put this in its own module and export the values you want, hiding the details of all this, but that seems like a lot of work for something so simple.

As commented below by hammar, the monomorphism restriction could cause trouble with the inferred type
of `banana`. To be safe, you should either annotate `banana` with its desired type (probably that of `apple`), or disable the monomorphism restriction as

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
import qualified Fruit as F (apple)
banana = F.apple
```

Otherwise, the inferred type of `banana` could be less polymorphic than desired.

The Monomorphism restriction attempts to assign a concrete instance of a type class for each top level function (this is done for performance reasons). Consider,

```
example = return ()
```

This function should have type `Monad m => m ()`, but due to the monomorphism restriction, there is not enough information about which Monad instance should be used, so you get the following message

```
Ambiguous type variable `m0' in the constraint:
  (Monad m0) arising from a use of `return'
Possible cause: the monomorphism restriction applied to the following:
  example :: m0 () (bound at Test.hs:44:1)
Probable fix: give these definition(s) an explicit type signature
              or use -XNoMonomorphismRestriction
In the expression: return ()
In an equation for `example': example = return ()
```

Now, if you provide enough information for GHC to infer which instance of Monad you are using, such as

```
example = return ()

main :: IO ()
main = example
```

then GHC will give the following type

```
*Main> :t example
example :: IO ()
```

since you told it that `example` will have the same type as `main`

Comment: Be wary of the monomorphism restriction when doing this, though, or `banana` may end up with a more restrictive type than `apple`.

Comment: @hammar for sure great advice. However for my limited understanding not detailed enough. Could you pls add an example?

Comment: @JFritsch I added more explanation with an example case of the monomorphism restriction.

Answer (score 8):

There's no syntax for that directly. Presumably you want to avoid a clash with a locally-defined `apple`, so I'd go with

```
import qualified Fruit (apple)
banana = Fruit.apple
```